# Erro de execução do JSF com Google Maps

Tags: jsf

estou fazendo um projeto e me deparei com uma situação desagradável. Pois bem, fiz um pequeno teste usando HTML5 em um bloco de notas utilizando o Google Maps deu tudo certo. Só que foi usar o código no meu projeto que utiliza o JSF + Glassfish. Quando executo a página o mapa aparece só que logo apresenta mensagem de erro "***Ops! Algo deu errado.Esta página não carregou o Google Maps corretamente. Consulte o console JavaScript para ver detalhes técnicos.***" . Não estou usando Classes Beans mas apenas expondo o Mapa só que isso não está funcionando.

Código da Pagina em XHMTL - JSF

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile">
    <f:view renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE" />
    <h:head>
        <link rel="icon" href="imagens/iconepag.png" type="image/x-icon" />
        <title>Peixe Fácil</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .ui-grid-a div {
                padding: 0em 0.5em;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAtx4Jj6jXIVnC0ckT97ZqoJnJo9fd0tbQ&amp;sensor=false&amp;callback=myMap"></script>
        <script>
            function myMap() {
                var lat = document.getElementById("lat").value;
                var long = document.getElementById("long").value;
                var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
                var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
                var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 15};
                var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myCenter});
                marker.setMap(map);

                // Zoom to 9 when clicking on marker
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    map.setZoom(9);
                    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                });
            }
        </script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <pm:page>
            <pm:header title="Peixe Fácil - Perfil" swatch="a">
                <p:button value="Home" icon="ui-icon-home" styleClass="ui-btn-left ui-btn-inline" href="PaginaInicial.jsf"/>
            </pm:header>
            <p:dataList value="Perfil" var="perfil"  paginator="false" >
                <p:graphicImage style="padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;border:#e6e6e6 solid 1px;height: 90px;width:90px ; border-radius: 100px;margin-top: 20px;margin-left: 5px;" url="imagens/#{mBLogin.nomeImagem}" />
                <p:dataList value="Nome: ">
                    <h2>Nome: </h2><h:outputText value="#{mBLogin.nome}" />
                    <h2>Apelido: </h2><h:outputText value="#{mBLogin.apelido}" />
                    <h2>E-mail: </h2><h:outputText value="#{mBLogin.email}" />
                    <h2>Idade: </h2><h:outputText value="#{mBLogin.idade}" />
                    <h2>Telefone: </h2><h:outputText value="#{mBLogin.telefone}" />
                    <h2>Localização: </h2>
                    <h:form id="form">
                        <p:gmap style="width:100%;height:15em" zoom="15" type="ROADMAP" center="41.381542, 2.122893" widgetVar="map"/>
                    </h:form>

                    <input type="text" value="#{mBLogin.latitude}" id="lat" onkeyup="myMap()"/>
                    <input type="text" value="#{mBLogin.longitude}" id="long" onkeyup="myMap()"/>

                </p:dataList>
            </p:dataList>

        </pm:page>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**Se alguém conseguir ou souber resolver agradeço!!**

Comment: Lembrando pessoal que so quero apresentar um Mapa na minha página, já revirei o site do Primefaces e nenhuma exemplo deles funcionou aparece a mesma coisa até msm o script que eles fornecem!

Comment: vc configuro a key de autorização que o google te passar ?

Comment: Pois é, eu tinha retirado e estava funcionando com HTML puro quando passavo pro jsf não funcionava mas conseguir resolver criando outra chave.